# AJAX HTTP Method GET Goes To Server Only Once

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, http

When I make ajax request to the server with breakpoint in the action method it stops on this breakpoint only the first time. After clicking for second, third etc. it goes but never stops on this breakpoint. When I change the method from `GET` to `POST` it stops every time. What is the reason for this behaviour ?

CLIENT SIDE:

```
$(function () {
    setListAction();
});

function setListAction() {
    $("li.list").on("click", function () {
        alert("active");
        var id = $(this).attr("file-id");

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "TechAcc/ManageFile/" + id,
            beforeSend: function myfunction() {
                $("#loading").css("display", "block");
                $("#fade").css("display", "block");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var content = $(data).find("div#content");
                $("div#content").html(content.html());

                $("#loading").css("display", "none");
                $("#fade").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

SERVER SIDE:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ManageFile(int id = 0)
        {
            FileModel model = null;

            if (id != 0)
                model = new FileModel() { File = _repository.GetFileBy(id), GetAllFiles = _repository.GetAllFiles() };
            else if (Session["Model"] != null)
                model = (FileModel)Session["Model"];
            else
                model = new FileModel() { GetAllFiles = _repository.GetAllFiles() };

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Strange if you mentioned whatever GET or POST it will get called each time you calling rather than unless there is a problem in ajax or anything ... What error you getting

Comment: I don't have any error in the console.

Comment: Your Browser is caching the ajax request...try adding a query string like timestamp...this will change url everytime and prevent caching!

Comment: If i have 3 <li> in <ul> after after clicking on each of them for first time it stops on this breakpoint. For second time clicking on each of them it doesn't work.

Comment: Check in console that is the ajax request is posting on URI or not in net tab

Comment: I solve this issue with $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });. The problem was that ajax request is cached in the browser. What means that this request is chached in the browser ? Is it going to the server or ? What it means ?

Comment: yes cache:false will solve the problem...but jquery recommends adding timestamp at end of get request along with cache:false...http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: and no its not going to server...

Comment: Ok I set again cache to true only for testing the behaviour but it don't cache the content now. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

if your div with id "content" has list, it will not work.

```
<div id="content">
if your list is here, it won't work.
...
<li class="list">...</li>
...
</div>
```

if your design is like that, you need to bind click event after you replace your HTML response. i.e.,

```
success: function (data) {
                var content = $(data).find("div#content");
                $("div#content").html(content.html());

                //adding code here.
                $("div#content").find("li.list").on("click", function() {
                //same above click code should come here.
                //Note: this newly added code block should not come here in click.
                });

                $("#loading").css("display", "none");
                $("#fade").css("display", "none");
            }
```